# What does flare your elbow mean in push ups/bench press

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have been having a hard time trying to figure out what an elbow flare means when I watch fitness videos on Youtube. It's been bugging me a lot. I think it apparently and roughly means the your elbow is bent to a certain degree with respect to your forearm? A few examples from Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=flare%20your%20elbow

Comment: "Flare" can mean bend or to spread outward, as in the flared "bell" of a trumpet, or to flare tubing for a fitting. So "bend outward" seems to be implied here.

Answer (score 1):

Elbow flare in this context is generally negative. It suggests, as you say, the elbow being out at an angle, when it is usually desirable to have a straight motion.

e.g. see the difference between image 1 and image 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first pic seems to have a better form. However to me it’s like it has more to do with the angle of your upper arm in relation to your torso than your elbow to your torso?